# What is Johnny Dee and the thing on his chest?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

[Johnny Dee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Dee) must have one of the weirdest abilities I've ever heard off. He has a tentacled face that makes voodoo dolls from peoples DNA growing out of his chest.

[image: Johnny Dee from Civil War X-Men Vol 1 3]

What is this thing?

There's some doubt as to whether he or the creature are one, or even mutants at all. The wikipedia link above doesn't give much info. Does anyone know what he is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Johnny Dee's powers have still not been confirmed as to whether they originate in his alien partner, or for that matter whether they are a mutation at all. When all other mutants had lost their abilities he retained his.

His power does not actually create "voodoo dolls." The term is used to denote the legends of the ability to kill or affect someone via a doll and using an unknown magic.

Johnny Dee needs to introduce a piece of DNA to his partner and then a construct (doll) is created that can be affected or even killed by damaging the doll construct. The mechanics of this power including its range, any limitations as to whom it can effect, or how long it lasts has not been determined.

Johnny Dee's whereabouts are currently unknown.

[image]

Comment: "Whereabouts unknown"?  How hard can it be to find someone with an octopus in their chest???

Comment: @dlanod - Literally the plotline of Total Recall